# LogConfigurationException when using HttpClient

Tags: java, maven, jira-plugin, apache-commons-httpclient

When my code executes this line:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I'm getting this Exception:

**org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log**

does somebody know how can I solve that?
Maybe is not important (or maybe it is), but the app is a plugin for Jira, and is using Maven for the dependencies.

Thanks !

EDIT: 
[image: stackTrace]

EDIT 2:
Could this be related with OSGi from Jira?

How can I use commons-logging in an OSGi environment?

From here:
http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Logging/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

> Commons-logging was not designed with OSGi in mind. This is why it is
>   difficult to get commons-logging working in OSGi environments:
>
> LogFactory loads Log implementations by name (see
>   Class.forName(String)). This is usually not possible in OSGi since
>   every bundle classloader can only see the classes a bundle defines
>   imports for. The bundle class loader that loads the commons-logging
>   bundle will not have access to user provided
>   commons-logging.properties files. commons-logging-api.jar contains
>   classes that are also included in commons-logging.jar. This is
>   contrary to traditional OSGi application architectures where one
>   bundle defines an API and other bundles provide implementations for
>   that API. There alternatives to using commons-logging directly in OSGi
>   are:
>
> Rebundled versions that contain proper OSGi meta data are available
>   from Apache Felix, SpringSource and Eclipse Orbit. Using Pax logging.
>   Further information about this topic is available in the archives of
>   the commons dev ML and the felix dev ML and in Jira.

and when I try to access to the OSGi tab from Jira (going to JIRASERVER/plugins/servlet/upm/osgi#osgi) I can see an exception:
**classNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory**

And also I can see from the IDE (when searching for Log4JLogger class) that I have two definitions:

```
package org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
public class Log4JLogger implements Log, Serializable {
```

and

```
package com.atlassian.extras.common.log;
class Log4jLogger implements com.atlassian.extras.common.log.Logger.Log {
```

this is really confusing....

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added an image with the Stack Trace, I hope it helps (right click and open the image in a new tab if you are seeing too small)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but could it be that the logger you configured does not correspond to the logger in your pom dependencies? Perhaps a different version?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check that Bart? I'm new in Maven, and I was fighting a lot with the dependencies there.